# Desabilitar fechas anteriores usando un DatePicker

Tags: java, android, date, datepicker

Quisiera poder desabilitar o no mostrar las fechas pasadas dentro de `DatePicker` android.

Actualmente mi `DatePicker` esta estructurado de esta manera:

```
        fechaDesdetxt.setOnClickListener(v ->{

        DatePickerFragment newFragment = DatePickerFragment.newInstance((view, year, month, dayOfMonth) ->  {
            Calendar g = Calendar.getInstance();
            g.set(year, month, dayOfMonth);
            SimpleDateFormat format_ = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM d yyyy");
            fechaDesdetxt.setText(format_.format(g.getTime()));
        });
        newFragment.show(NewEventActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager(), "DatePickerInFullD");

    });
```

O ¿existe alguna librería para esto tal vez?

Answer (score 2):

Veo que usas un `Fragment` el cual seguramente implementa `DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener` .

### Como deshabilitar fechas pasadas en un DatePicker.

Te sugiero usar el método [setMinDate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#setMinDate(long)) , como ejemplo, esto deshabilitaría días anteriores a la fecha actual:

```
  myDatePicker.setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
```

---

Esto es un ejemplo usando un `Fragment` llamado `DatePickerFragment`, similar a tu pregunta.

Para instanciar el `Fragment` defines la fecha mínima que soportará el `DatePicker` con un formato `dd/MM/yyyy`, lo que realiza esta clase es convertir la fecha en millisegundos y asignarla al método [setMinDate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#setMinDate(long)) :

```
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    private static String minDate="";
    public static Fragment newInstance(String minDateSupported ) {
        minDate  = minDateSupported;
        DatePickerFragment myFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        return myFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Configura la fecha actual.
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        //Crea una nueva instancia de DatePickerDialog y la retorna.
        DatePickerDialog dPickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);

        //Define una fecha minima.
        //Esto deshabilita fechas anteriores.
        dPickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(convertDateToMillis(minDate));
        return dPickerDialog;
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        //Realiza algo con la fecha seleccionada por el usuario.
    }

    //givenDateString must be defined in format dd/MM/yyyy
    private Long convertDateToMillis(String givenDateString){
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        long timeInMilliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000;
        try {
            Date mDate = sdf.parse(givenDateString);
            timeInMilliseconds = mDate.getTime();
            System.out.println("Date in milliseconds: " + timeInMilliseconds);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return timeInMilliseconds;
    }

}
```

Usando la clase anterior, como ejemplo, si deseas deshabilitar fechas antes del 5 de Enero del 2019 como ejemplo puedes definir como fecha mínima "05/01/2019" al instanciar el `Fragment`:

```
DialogFragment newFragment = (DialogFragment) DatePickerFragment.newInstance("05/01/2019");
newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
```

tendrás como resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: seria igual para permitir una fecha maxima??

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez exacto, también debe funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Dentro de `onCreateDialog` de tu `DatePickerFragment` configuras la fecha mínima y máxima a 
mostrar. Aquí un ejemplo, fecha hoy 01/02/2018, muestra un mes antes (01/01/2019)
y un mes después (01/03/2019) de la fecha de hoy:

```
   DatePickerDialog picker;  // primero declaras el picker antes de onCreateDialog

   // dentro de onCreateDialog:
   picker = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), dateSetListener, year, month, day);

    Date today = new Date(); // obtienes la fecha de hoy
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();  // instancias el Calendar
    c.setTime(today);     // parseas la fehca de hoy a millis
    c.add( Calendar.MONTH, -1 ); // restas 1 mes 
    long minDate = c.getTime().getTime(); // obtienes en long la fecha (un mes menos)

    c.setTime(today);
    c.add( Calendar.MONTH, 1 );  // agregas un mes más
    long maxDate = c.getTime().getTime();

    picker.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(maxDate); // aquí seteas al picker la fecha a mostrar
    picker.getDatePicker().setMinDate(minDate);

    return picker;
```